# Word for describing a quote that makes you realize that it's true

Tags: single-word-requests

When you read some quotes, it gives a feeling. You realise that it is profoundly true and it brings a smile on your face as you admire the brilliance in it. Is there a word to describe this feeling?

For example I got that feeling when I read this quote:

> the depth of your attention determines the depth of your experience. If your attention is profoundly, your experience of life is profoundly.

Comment: The quotation struck a chord with you. How about this? And you may want to fix the quotation that impressed you so: Omit "ly" from "profoundly"! :)

Comment: That quotation is ungrammatical. In the second sentence (I assume the lowercase *t* in the first sentence is a typo), *profoundly* needs to be replaced with *profound*. If that's a verbatim quote, and also not at typo, it's not a very *profound* sentence. (Pun intended.)

Comment: @JasonBassford Or maybe you just don't get how profoundly it's written. :)

Comment: Given at the duplicate: 'epiphany', 'eureka moment', 'it blew me away', 'it took my breath away' ....

Answer (score 0):

You are probably referring to an ***[epiphany](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/epiphany)***

> a moment when you suddenly feel that you understand, or suddenly become conscious of, something  that is very important to you.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion of "epiphany" is good, but another common expression is to be *enlightened*. [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/enlightened?s=t) defines it as

> privy to or claiming a sense of spiritual or religious revelation of truth

but I've frequently heard it used more broadly (essentially treating any particular sphere of knowledge as metaphorically religious).